# Unity + Wwise iOS build stops playing sound when screen is locked

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, wwise

My audio app plays various sounds when it's active. When I press the lock button the sounds stop. If I tap the screen to reveal the wallpaper (device still locked) the sounds are back on, once the screen dims sounds are off.

When the screen dims I get

`AK Error: Voice Starvation`

I read that this has to do with low processing power/lack of resources but my app has less than 5 voices. It just plays a loop with occasional sounds. Also the profiler tells me that the app is consuming <0.5% of CPU. No large spikes.

I tried adding the following code to `UnityAppController.mm`

```
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error: nil];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

It had no effect

I have Wwise configured to
[image]

It has no effect.

I have the following background behaviour enabled for ios
[image]

I tried adding

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Update()
  {
    AkSoundEngine.WakeupFromSuspend();
    AkSoundEngine.RenderAudio();
  }
}
```

No effect either.

All I want to achieve is allow my app to play sounds while the screen is locked *and* dimmed, similar to Spotify, etc. (I don't need any audio controls). I've tried for months to find a solution but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Unity does not provide this feature out of the box. The answer to the same question is described in detail [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197908/how-to-play-audio-in-unity-when-a-mobile-game-runs-in-the-background-or-the-scre).